# Is there an open source implementation of an 802.1X authenticator?

Tags: networking, security, authentication, 802.1x, physical-security

I'm aware of Xsupplicant, but it seems to only implement the "client" side of the handshake.  The authenticator side, which handles the other side of the EAPOL handshake, and interfaces to RADIUS (presumably FreeRADIUS for our testing) I don't see anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. `hostapd` does this. I'm 99% sure it can be configured to act as the 802.1X authenticator for a wired Ethernet interface as well, even though it's primarily considered a wireless tool.